# Adding meta tags in header in Lithium PHP

Tags: php, lithium

I am trying to add meta data tags in header, this is my code:

app/extensions/helper/FacebookHtml.php

```
<?php
namespace app\extensions\helper;

class FacebookHtml extends \lithium\template\Helper {

protected $_strings = array(
    'title' => '<meta property="og:title" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'site_name' => '<meta property="og:site_name" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'url' => '<meta property="og:url" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'description' => '<meta property="og:description" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'image' => '<meta property="og:image" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'image' => '<meta property="og:image" content="{:contenido}" />',
    'locate' => '<meta property="og:locate" content="{:contenido}" />',
);

public function meta($contenido, $options) {
    return $this->_render(__METHOD__, $options['type'], compact('contenido'));
}
}
```

In app/views/layout/default.html.php, inside

`<?=$this->FacebookHtml(); ?>`

In other view file:

`<?=$this->FacebookHtml->meta('title', 'Test.. 1...2...3...'); ?>`

I look for hours in Google and in the core code to know how to add metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First a few notes:**

In your example, `<?=$this->FacebookHtml(); ?>` doesn't do anything.

Like Oerd said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33225304/627213), your parameters are incorrect. They should match your function declaration in `FacebookHtml.php` It should be:

```php
<?= $this->FacebookHtml->meta('Test.. 1...2...3...', array('type' => 'title')); ?>
```

---

Your helper does exactly what it's supposed to, rendering the raw meta tags. Where you call your helper is important. As it stands, you are just rendering the meta tags in place. However, the li3 Renderer class provides the `$this->head()` method which does two things.

1. Passing a value to `head` adds it to the context for all templates using the current Renderer. Example: `$this->head("<meta property="og:title" content="The Title" />");`
2. Echoing `$this->head()` will render all the tags held in the current `head` context.

Here's some real world examples:

**app/views/layouts/default.html.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <?php echo $this->head() ?>

    <title><?php echo $this->title(); ?> | My Website</title>

</head>

<body>

    <?php echo $this->content(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**app/views/pages/index.html.php**

```php
<?php $this->FacebookHtml->meta('Test.. 1...2...3...', array('type' => 'title')); ?>
```

The example above allows you to specify any headers you want inside of your views.

In addition to `$this->head()`, li3 also provides `$this->styles()` and `$this->scripts()` with similar functionality.

Check the default.html.php sample from the li3 framework repository for a more complete example: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/app/views/layouts/default.html.php

Comment: Awesome!!! It was really simple in fact! Thanks for your time and knowledge mate, really appreciate!! You are the man, cheers!!

Comment: Great answer... nailed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your view templates, you have to call the helper by providing `title` in the options array:

```
<?= $this->facebookHtml->meta('Test.. 1...2...3...', array('type' => 'title')); ?>
```

I'm sure you've already gone through it, but here is the [Lithium manual page on helpers](http://li3.me/docs/manual/views/helpers.md)

Comment: Thank for your answer. But that don't display the og:title metadata in the <head> section :(

I want to put the meta tags inside <head>

Comment: then you most probably have to change the `app/views/layouts/default.html.php` file. I.e. *not* in your view template, but in the master layout

Comment: Don't get you, it would be really awesome if you can help me with this by show me a example, I am stucked with this long time ago :(